# How to get your PING and put it on a label

Tags: c#, winforms, ping

I was trying to find how to get my ping and found this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply pingreply = ping.Send("www.google.com");
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ping.txt");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("Address: " + pingreply.Address + "\r\n");
                sb.Append("Roundtrip Time: " + pingreply.RoundtripTime + "\r\n");
                sb.Append("TTL (Time To Live): " + pingreply.Options.Ttl + "\r\n");
                sb.Append("Buffer Size: " + pingreply.Buffer.Length.ToString() + "\r\n");
                sb.Append("Time : " + DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
                sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
label1.Text = pingreply.Buffer.Length.ToString();
```

But it didn't work to get the ping,
and i can't figure out how to get it on a label, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Probably there was an error but you, for some odd reason, are catching all exceptions and throwing the error message away.  Can you explain why you have done that?

Comment: I'm not sure what "the ping" is, but most of the time people would be most interested in the `pingreply.RoundtripTime`.

Comment: What do you mean, "get your ping"?

Comment: Also, FYI, half the reason to use a StringBuilder is to avoid string concatenation. Don't do that. Use, `sb.AppendFormat("Time : {0}\r\n", DateTime.Now)`

Comment: @Dozer789, for what it's worth, this is an excellent example of why learning by copying/pasting is a poor approach.  It's better to see sample code, and *literally type out* your own version, making sure you understand what each line of *your* code is doing as you type it.  If you follow that approach, you gain a richer understanding and generally avoid the trap of repeating other people's bugs.

Comment: I don't ever copy and paste, everyone that answers my questions always thinks that i copy and paste but whenever i see code examples for what i am doing, i always write it out myself because like you were saying, you learn more typing it out than by copying and pasting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are catching all errors and ignoring them.. probably caused by your attempt at writing it to a file.

Just do this:

```
label1.Text = new Ping().Send("www.google.com").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
```

Or, properly disposing (thanks @Ichabod Clay)

```
using (Ping p = new Ping()) {
    label1.Text = p.Send("www.google.com").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
}
```

Comment: Just what i needed, thanks, and i will accept your answer in 8 minutes (i have to wait that long to accept)

Comment: A slightly off topic question, but will the `Ping` object be properly closed/disposed after this line has executed?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't realise `Ping` was `IDisposable`. Edited. Thanks :)